# Algebraic role of Dottie number

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Consider an algebraic system, which we would call "anti-dual numbers", which is defined on a plane with a unit "circle" of the form of lemniscate (two adjanced circles) $r(\phi)=|\cos(\phi)|$:

[image]

Each number on this plane would be represented as a pair of real numbers $(a,b)$. We also allow complex $(a,b)$ for generality, which makes our space 4-dimensional.
We define $arg (a,b)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{a b}{a^2+b^2}+\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)$ and $mod (a,b)=\frac{a^2+b^2}{a}$ (these functions only correspond to modulus and argument on the right half-plane, and serve us as intermediate tools for calculations).
When two numbers are added, their components are added components-wise and when two numbers are multiplied, their arg's are added up and mod's multiplied.

Below is the Mathematica code:

```
arg[{a_, b_}] := 1/2 ((a b)/(a^2 + b^2) + ArcTan[b/a])
mod[{a_, b_}] := (a^2 + b^2)/a
angle[A_] := ArcSin[Sqrt[InverseBetaRegularized[4 A/Pi, 1/2, 3/2]]]
X[m_, A_] := m Cos[angle[A]] Abs[Cos[angle[A]]]
Y[m_, A_] := m Sin[angle[A]] Abs[Cos[angle[A]]]
Multiply[{a1_, b1_}, {a2_, b2_}] := {X[mod[{a1, b1}] mod[{a2, b2}], 
   arg[{a1, b1}] + arg[{a2, b2}]], 
  Y[mod[{a1, b1}] mod[{a2, b2}], arg[{a1, b1}] + arg[{a2, b2}]]}
```

This system is commutative and associative but not distributive. But multiplication by its subset, complex numbers is distributive against addition.

But there is an interesting fact: the number $\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-D^2}\right),\frac{D}{2}\right)$, where $D$ is Dottie number is nilpotent: squared it gives $0$. This is because the vector of this number divides the upper-right half-circle into two parts of equal area of $\pi/16$ (thus giving the argument $arg \left(1-\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-D^2}\right),\frac{D}{2}\right)= \pi/8$ as argument is twice the area, similar to complex, dual and split-complex numbers). The modulus of this number is $1$.

```
In:=Multiply[{1 - (1 - Sqrt[1 - Dottie^2])/2, Dottie/
   2}, {1 - (1 - Sqrt[1 - Dottie^2])/2, Dottie/2}] // N
Out:={0., 0.}
```

Notice that the modulus of zero is undetermined.

I wonder, does this have any algebraic significance, sheding light at the algebraic role of Dottie number?

Comment: You have some bizarre algebraic system defined using the lemniscate (that is, the cosine). The Dottie number is the fixed point of the cosine. Is it really so strange that the two things are related?

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko complex numbers are created by circle, yet it is interesting that $\pi$ has an algebraic role there.

Comment: Why do you think that there is an algebraic role of the Dottie number? I can't see any motivation which suggests there might be a role that Dottie numbers could play.

Comment: @BenMcKay because $\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-D^2}\right),\frac{D}{2}\right)$ is a nilpotent in this system.